# Some of the questions look disabled?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, design, user-interface

Some of the questions look disabled for just one tag (Selenium Webdriver - SO), this is listed as my favorite tags. I am able to work on them but still didn't understand what its trying to indicate?[image]

Comment: What are your "ignored" tags?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this and @Antony, I don't think this is a duplicate.  The OP is wondering why some questions look disabled, not about the coloring of favorite tag questions.

Comment: I don't have any ignored tags

Comment: Are these questions that *you've looked at already?*

Comment: No i haven't clicked on these questions...whats interesting is `all these questions are tagged with the combination of Selenium and Selenium WebDriver (both are my favorite tags)`..This is the only common thing i could find in them

Comment: @CodeMaverick So what do you mean by "look disabled" if it is not about the color?

Comment: @Amith003 You need to double check your favorite/ignored tags. I have once encountered something like this and it was caused by an overly greedy * in my ignored tags matching things that I didn't intend to.

Comment: @Antony - My bad, I didn't read the answer to that duplicate.  The question isn't a duplicate, but the answer definitely answers this question.

Comment: @Antony - I haven't added any ignored tags

Comment: @Antony - you were right, i didn't know ignored tags were hidden and somehow it got added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of what the duplicate says, I find that if I go to a /tagged/ URL, questions tagged with *one* of my favorites will have a white background, while questions with *two or more* of my favorite tags will have a yellowish background.

On dba.se, for example, two of my favorite tags are [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server) and [sql-server-2008-r2](/questions/tagged/sql-server-2008-r2). Here are the first two questions on [https://dba.stackexchange.com/tagged/sql-server/](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-server/):

> [image]

Similarly, on Stack Overflow, at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server/, I've marked my favorite tags with a little red star:

> [image]

You can see that questions with more than one of my favorite tags have a darker background color.

The duplicate does say this, but it wasn't clear to me on first pass:

> Note that when viewing a question list within one or more of your interesting tags, only questions with one or more additional interesting tags will be highlighted.

So, on the home page, you would see yellow background for any question with one of your favorite tags. On a tag page, it requires at least one additional tag.

Greyed out means that those questions have at least one of your ignored tags (possibly in addition to one or more of your favorite tags). So I would suspect that you have added `casperjs` and either `c#` or `iframe` to your list of ignored tags. You can remove those, of course, but you can change this behavior in [your preferences page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/2862485/) (only @Amith003 will see anything there), opting to hide ignored tags instead of greying them out:

> [image]

Comment: I didn't know hidden tags were hidden, just checked it to find one of the tags as ignored...i'm not sure how it got added though..

Comment: @Amith003 sometimes you can just be typing and inadvertently tab + enter into a textbox you didn't mean to, and not realize...

Comment: got it, thanks for the explanation...But If a tag is listed under `favorites` i don't think it should be allowed to be added as ignored,because it doesn't make sense to include a tag in favorite as well as ignored.

Comment: @Amith003 I'd agree with that - file it as a bug I guess, though it may be by design, so it may need to change to a feature request. You should update your question though, and explain which tag(s) were favorites, which tag(s) were ignored, and update your comments to reflect that you did, in fact, have ignored tags. You brushed a bunch of people off who made that suggestion, and it turned out to be the case...

Comment: ya,will do that